# Not possible to make this reference

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason I keep getting an error when i try this code

```
Set chtObj = ActiveWorkbook.Sheet2.ChartObjects.Add(Range("D3:M20").Left, Range("D3:M20").Top, Range("D3:M20").Width, Range("D3:M20").Height)
```

Comment: try changing `Sheet2` for `Sheets(2)`

Comment: "I keep getting an error" - what error exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Would be better written using a `With`, to ensure your ranges don't default to some other worksheet:

```
With Sheet2.Range("D3:M20")
    Set chtObj = .Parent.ChartObjects.Add(.Left, .Top, _
                                          .Width, .Height)
End With
```

You may need to adjust the worksheet reference (depending on exactly what error it is you're getting).

Comment: suggest this: `With Sheet2.Range("D3:M20"):    Set chtObj = Sheet2.ChartObjects.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height):     End With`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the error you are getting ? The `Set` statement must be declared inside a procedure.

I tried it quickly and the following code complile without problem.

```
Sub foo()
Dim chtObj As ChartObject
Set chtObj = Worksheets("Sheet2").ChartObjects.Add(Range("D3:M20").Left, Range("D3:M20").Top, Range("D3:M20").Width, Range("D3:M20").Height)
End Sub
```